# How to check if device has flashlight

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to check if device has a flash light.

I know I can switch it off and on with Xamarin Essentials.

```
 await Flashlight.TurnOnAsync();
// Turn Off
await Flashlight.TurnOffAsync();
```

But I can't seem to find out how to only check if its present ?

Many iPads in iOS doesn't have it and

Comment: if will throw a `FeatureNotSupportedException` if it is not supported

Comment: You could also write your own service if you want to check it before turning it on. The Xamarin Essentials github pages show where they are checking for torch functionality on [iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Xamarin.Essentials/Flashlight/Flashlight.ios.cs#L24) and [Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Xamarin.Essentials/Flashlight/Flashlight.android.cs#L21). It wouldn't be too hard to write your own service to do those checks separately.

Comment: Wow, I was sure it was in Xamarin.Essentials -- sounds like a good thing to ask for, or to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FeatureNotSupportedException` exception:

```
try
{
    // Turn On
    await Flashlight.TurnOnAsync();

    // Turn Off
    await Flashlight.TurnOffAsync();
}
catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
{
    // Handle not supported on device exception
  //This exception is called when the device does not have a flashlight
}
catch (PermissionException pEx)
{
    // Handle permission exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Unable to turn on/off flashlight
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/flashlight?tabs=android